# ArcGIS - World Imagery Map Service - Force Higher Resolution Imagery

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service, arcglobe

I am using the [ArcGIS world imagery map service](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9) in an ArcGlobe project. Based on the scale and perspective of my view, imagery updates between different resolutions.

Sometimes two resolutions are shown at once resulting in choppy imagery.
[image]

I can see that this Map Service is made up of many different resolutions that display at different zoom levels.

Is there a map service that will only show the more detailed imagery below? I believe this is the I-Cubed 15m data.

Is there a way to force arcGlobe to display the higher resolution imagery?

Comment: do you have ArcGIS server?

Comment: I do not have ArcGIS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esri makes these cached services available on their data download (with subscription).

esri data and maps for server
[image: DAMFS]

The data includes pre-rendered tiles.  But if I am not mistaken with that to start with you could create your own tiled service and modify the thresholds.
It would take up "CONSIDERABLE" space.

The ArcGIS online data would not even contain tiles for scales outside of the thresholds.

You will need either...
1. a subscription service for higher resolution
(like Bing Maps for Enterprise 
http://www.microsoft.com/maps),
[Spatial Energy](http://www.spatialenergy.com)
or there may be others.
2. Or your own basemap information (which is not impossible to compile) [BUT very difficult to maintain/update/ground truth], and a server/online cache-tile creation system.  Then a way to serve them.